# IIS 7 Url Rewrite with virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7

I have a aspx website in IIS7, with a virtual folder in the root (called '**app**'), which is another aspx application.

I want **www.main.com/section** to show contents from **www.other.com/page**.
However, **www.main.com/section/app**, I want to ignore the previous redirection (it will virtual folder contents).

I can't get this to work. This is what I have:

```
<rule name="Landing page" enabled="true">
  <match url="landing" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.other.com/page" />
</rule>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you have to add conditions to your re-write rule.

Comment: This reference might help https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rule_action Specifically the `AbortRequest` `<action>` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers.

I guess I have to use [url rewrite and Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).